# Using ramps on-load

Tags: ramps-1.4

I have a RAMPS 1.4 with Arduino Mega 2560 with 2 steppers connected to an external power supply using Polulo stepper drivers. The steppers are for X and Y axis movement. This external power supply is set to 12 volts and power is applied. I have configured the marlin firmware also.

Can I connect my setup to my PC using USB when the external power is also on? If i connect the USB while the external power is off, do the motors take power from USB? Will this will burn my board?

Answer (score 0):

*Can I connect my setup to my PC using USB when the external power is also on?*
As long as you are connecting the external power to the correct pins, yes you can.

*If i connect the USB while the external power is off, do the motors take power from USB?*
No, the motors need an external power supply.